# Using Latest version of Jenkins, it's not updating Artifactory Pro libs-release-local directory

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, artifactory, artifacts

In Jenkins configuration we have our Artifactory URL entered.

We have a Maven job defined using Artifactory Plugin.

With settings as follows;

```
Build Environment:
  Enable Artifactory release management is unchecked
  Resolve artifacts from Artifactory is unchecked


Post-Build Actions
  Artifact Server = valid url
  Target releases repository = libs-release-local
  Target snapshot repository = libs=snapshot-local
  Custom stating configuration = None
  Deploy maven artifacts = checked
  Filter exclude artifacts from build Info = checked
```

For some reason we're not able to push our war file to libs-release-local, goes to libs-snapshot-local just fine.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`libs-release-local` accepts releases only, `libs-snapshot-local` accepts snapshots only.

Since your war might be only release or snapshot, but not both, it's only natural that you deploy it to one of the repositories, but not the other.